# Unable to connect R with Youtube API

Tags: r, youtube

I am trying to connect with the youtube API using yt_oauth function but getting error as follows :

```
Error in readRDS(token) : error reading from connection.
```

I have checked my application several times. First I got the API Key and then the Client ID and Client Secret. I am using the Client ID and Client Secret for app_id and app_secret below. I have enabled all the 3 youtube APIs(Data,Analytics,Reporting)So where can I be going wrong? Any help appreciated.

Below is the code I am using

```
library("tuber")
app_id <- "XYZ"
app_secret<-"abc"

yt_oauth(app_id,app_secret)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you called **yt_oauth** previously with some invalid parameter. A file called **.httr-oauth** may exists at your current path (in my case it was on *My Documents* folder). One can remove that file or alternatively do this:

```
yt_oauth(app_id, app_secret, token = '')
```

It will force tuber to refresh the token state.